# keepassx doesnt work

Tags: keepassx

I made a new user and copied my password library over to the new account , after copying and giving rights with chmod keepass said it isnt a valid library.

(Thank you to the guy who corrects my spelling and grammar)

Answer (score 1):

Install `kpcli` package which need for authenticcation in `keepassx`.

```
sudo apt-get install kpcli
```

Comment: is alredy installed and updated